# How to fix blocking error when receiving data on non-blocking socket

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, tcp

I'm trying to create a simple echo server that can handle multiple connections, I am using select and need to use non blocking sockets but I get an error saying 'BlockingIOError: [Errno 35] Resource temporarily unavailable' on the line where I receive the data.

Here's the server and client code

```
inputs = [server]

while True:
    inready, outready, excready = select.select(inputs, [], [])

    for s in inready:
        if s == server:
            client, address = server.accept()
            client.setblocking(0)
            print(address)
            inready.append(client)

        else:
            data = s.recv(1024);
            if data:
                s.send(data)
            else:
                inputs.remove(s)
                s.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

This little error took me also a while to find:

```
            inready.append(client)
```

Correct is, of course:

```
            inputs.append(client)
```

Since `inready` was accidentally modified, the `else` block was executed when it shouldn't have been.

Comment: This is life saver! I had the same problem lol! I smash that thumb up button!